# Como usar o setInterval acionando com o click usando addEventListener no javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval, event-listener

javascript.js explicação - já está funcioando o codigo e ele mostraa resposta "bahia" letra por letra de 2 em 2 segundo, porem não preciso nem clicar pra aparecer a resposta(está funcionando como se tivesse onLoad). alguem sabe o porque a função está sendo acionada de imediato e não aguarda o addEventListener ?

```
let resposta01 = "bahia";
let resp01 = resposta01.split('');
let i = 0; 

let whereAnser01 = document.querySelector(".resp01")
whereAnser01.addEventListener("click", slowAnser(resp01, whereAnser01));

function slowAnser(resp, whereAnser){
    
    var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
        
        whereAnser.innerHTML += resp[i];
        i++
    }, 2000);            

    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervalo);
    }, resp.length *2000);
```

Comment: olá Luan, só olhando para esse código não da pra saber, coloque todo o código, incluindo a parte relevante do html

Comment: Você passou o resultado da execução de slowAnser para o addEventListener, você teria que passar o nome da função, dessa forma: `whereAnser01.addEventListener("click", 'slowAnser');`, mas aí você vai ter que ver uma forma de passar esses parâmetros resp e whereAnser para dentro da função slowAnser.

Comment: benilson é isso mesmo desse jeito funcionou ! obrigado.só que a dor de cabeça agora é justamente essa se não automatizar essa função pra ela sempre saber o que fazer com a resposta e onde exibi-la ... eu vou ter que clonar essa função em todo lugar que eu queira que exiba uma resposta. Obrigado ai! se alguem souber um jeito de pegar os parametros ... ajudaria muito. Sucesso. (como que marco que sua resposta funcionou?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@LuanAugusto, como resposta ao seu último comentário, você poderia passar uma função anônima para o método `addEventListener()`. Assim você poderia passar os parâmetros que quisesse.

```js
// ...
/* Esse é o seu código antigo
whereAnser01.addEventListener("click", slowAnser(resp01, whereAnser01)); */
whereAnser01.addEventListener("click", () => slowAnser(resp01, whereAnser01));
// ...
```